# Have I found an error here?

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Let $f : [a, b] → R$ be a Riemann integrable function and let $F$ be a continuously differentiable function on $R$. Prove that $g(x) = F(f(x))$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b]$.

I was given the following solution:

Consider the difference between upper and lower Riemann sum under a partition $P$ of $[a, b]$.
On the $i$-th interval, $\overline{S_i}(F(f(x)),P)- \underline{S_i}(F(f(x)),P)=[F(f(x_i))-F(f(x_{i-1}))]\Delta x_i$
... and the proof continues.

I stopped reading here and got confused. How does this equality hold? Is this a mistake? Isn't the author assuming that $F(f(x))$ is increasing, when that assumption was not given in the problem statement?

Comment: I think the right terms are upper and lower Darboux sums. The problem can be handled by noting that both upper and lower Darboux sums can be approximated by suitable Riemann sums and then applying mean value theorem (and the fact that $F'$ is continuous and therefore bounded). Let me know if you need such a proof (and you may indicate this by updating the post).

Comment: Also the proof in the post is wrong. I wonder if this is an issue with solutions manual. Usually solution manual is not given the same care as the main textbook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with you: this statement depends on $F \circ f$ being a weakly increasing function, which is not an assumption in the claim you stated.

My best guess is that the solution is wrong. My second-best guess is that you've accidentally looked up a solution to a different exercise from the one you intended - like maybe a different edition of the book has a different exercise #3 that does involve increasing functions, or something like that.